# Default values within a class

Tags: ios, swift

Lets just say i have the following class:

```
class car {
    var brand = ["BWM", "Ford", "Audi","Toyota"
    var color = ["Red", "Blue", "White", "Black"
    var speed = Double()
    var weight = Double()
}
```

I have a UITableView that allows the user to add a row, and pick a new car based on the brand.

Now lets say all BMWs are red, so color is set to red. 
I think I could achieve this by adding:

```
Init(){
If brand == "BMW"{
color = "red"}
```

But I also want to set defaults for other brands, and this seems like a long way of doing things. Is there an easier way?

Comment: you can use dictionary for that, or index of the array. "BMW":"Red" or if index of the array 1 color red, index 2 color green...depends on the context

Comment: You can use enums if you want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should re-evaluate your class. A single car doesn't have multiple brands, so your `brand` property should be an enumeration, as should your colour.

Once you define a Car class, A BMW is then a subclass of a `Car` where you override the initialisation behaviour:

```
enum CarBrand {
    case BMW
    case Ford
    case Audi
    case Toyota
}

enum CarColor {
    case Red
    case Blue
    case White
    case Black
}

class Car {
    var brand: CarBrand
    var color: CarColor
    var weight: Double
    var maxSpeed: Double

    init(brand: CarBrand, color: CarColor, weight: Double, maxSpeed: Double) {
        self.brand = brand
        self.color = color
        self.weight = weight
        self.maxSpeed = maxSpeed
    }
}

class BMWCar : Car {
    init(weight: Double, maxSpeed: Double) {
        super.init(brand: .BMW, color: .Red, weight: weight, maxSpeed: maxSpeed)
}


let aCar = Car(brand: .Audi, color: .Blue, weight: 1760, maxSpeed: 200)

let aBMWCar = BMWCar(weight: 1800, maxSpeed: 220)
```

Strictly speaking `Car` should be an abstract class, but this isn't supported directly in Swift.

Comment: This seems like a very unscalable approach. Creating a distinct subclass for each model car violates basic object oriented design. A `BMWCar` is not a specialized type of `Car`. It is a `Car` with specific values for the `Car` properties. This answer is analogous to subclassing `UILabel` for each label that has a different background color.

Comment: I agree to an extent, but I think the situation in the question is fairly contrived.  Why would all BMWs be red? The OP was effectively asking about constraining one property based on another during initialisation.  There are other issues with my answer too; there should be an override on the `color` setter to prevent a BMW's color being changed.  But to your point, if you wanted to constrain a `UILabel`'s background color based on it's font you would have to subclass since you can't modify the `UILabel` initialiser.

Comment: The question is really, where does "business logic" belong; you could implement it in the calling application by simply providing the color and brand to `Car()` or you can implement a subclass that implements the specialised behaviour.  In this sense, my answer uses object-oriented design to override behaviour

Comment: The last sentence of the question talks about setting defaults. That's just data, not business logic.

Comment: Fair enough, so in that case the answer is neither to subclass nor to modify `init` but rather simply pass the correct properties through the `init` method from the calling class.  Unfortunately my answer is accepted, so I can't delete it.

Comment: My ambiguous question is probably to blame. My actual scenario is a bit more complicated so thought I would simplify things. I'm creating a payments table. Each payment has a name, a type (taxable, non taxable etc), a multiplier (hourly rate, salary etc) and a value. The users clicks an empty 'Add pay item' row and selects a name by a UIpicker. Some items like type will be locked and set by default. Some amendable via a textfield. Pauls answer seems to work for me, but if you would like me to un-accept incase it misleads others let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You could also declare a new class BMW that is a subclass of car and set the color to red in the init method.